# Spring's JdbcTemplate read only connection exception

Tags: spring, jdbc

I've a function updating a database table using Spring's JdbcTemplate and for some reason there was exception about the fact that the connection is read only and can't update any database related changes. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the transaction property. Is it Read-Only?
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html

Try adding this to the datasource defination

```
    <property name="defaultReadOnly">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: This would rather solve the problem... Thank you for reply.. But actually i had given a property to Transaction advice like this and it was causing the problem....

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">

        <tx:attributes>

            <tx:method name="save*"/>

            <!--  <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/> -->

        </tx:attributes>

    </tx:advice>


As u can see i had now commented the code of line which are making my all methods connection read only...

Again Thanks for the reply.